# How is if condition different from JUnit's assumingThat?

Tags: java, junit

Why would one use `JUnit`'s assumingThat() method instead of a plain old simple if clause? If one can use simple thing why would you complicate it with something else that does it the same way.

Is it just a expressionality thing, or what's the advantage, I don't see other benefits.

Comment: please mark as answer, if I had sufficiently answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Junit`'s `assume` is not a new feature in version 5, it has been there since v4.4 and it has other applications.

You could skip testing with `if`, but with `assume` you can tag failure lifecycle [method](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html#testAssumptionFailure(org.junit.runner.notification.Failure)) to it, using a `Listener`.

Example Situation (Most Common) - You could have a listener, which creates reports of the test. And there could be a code to add the failed tests, passed tests and assume failed tests to the report. If you want to achieve this without using listener or `testAssumptionFailure` method, then you would have to repeatedly call it everywhere.

Instead adding a listener makes it modular and maintainable.

You have many varities of `assume` [methods](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) which you could use to stop repeatedly write `if`, `else` and messages.